# solving nonlinear equations including max function

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I want to solve this system of equations using MATLAB:

[image]

I solved the second equation and put it in the first one. Then I tried this:

```
syms v_star
eqn = max((1.8+0.81*v_star), (-1+0.9*v_star)) == v_star;
solx = solve(eqn,v_star)
```

And I get this error:

```
Error using symengine
Input arguments must be convertible to floating-point numbers.
```

How can I solve this system of equations?

Comment: 2nd equation must have a typo, it makes no sense to compute the max of two identical quantities.

Comment: What `version` of Matlab are you using? I'm unable to replicate your error in R2022b.

Comment: Thank you, but there is no typo. That is the right equation. And I'm using Matlab 2018b.